# UIBarButtonItem icon white when added via IB, black when added programmatically

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, uibarbuttonitem

When I add an icon to a `UIBarButtonItem` via the Interface Builder, the icon is displayed white. When I add the same icon file programmatically to another `UIToolbar`, the icon is displayed black. Why?

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setImage:image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
rootViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:reloadButton] autorelease];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Everything Jongsma said is right, you should use the initWithImage:style: message.

The next problem is not the way you create the `UIBarButtonItem`, but the place you assign it. You create it with UIBarButtonItemStylePlain, which should normally render the icon's outline in white, but the rightBarButtonItem of a UINavigationItem (just like the left)  is not allowed the UIBarButtonItemStylePlain. It's implicitly converted to UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered. In the bordered style the icon is rendered 'as is', which is black with a slight gradient.

I think if you want the item in white on a bordered barButton, you'll have to touch the image itself.

Comment: But why is the image displayed in white when I add it via Interface Builder?

Comment: You are adding it as rightBarButtonItem via InterfaceBuilder? That appears black when I test it.

Comment: The image appears white, if the `UIBarButtonItemStylePlain` is used, it appears black with a button around it, with the `UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered`

Answer (score 6):

Answer: *If you want it white, color your image white.*

**Details:**

UIBarButtonItems behave a little differently depending on how you use them.

**When adding to a `UIToolbar`:**

`initWithImage:style:target:action:` creates "white icons" (image color is ignored, opaque pixels are used as a mask to create a white image).
*This is true for `bordered` and `plain` styles (but on UIToolbar only).*

`initWithCustomView:` displays normal colored image.

**When adding to a `UINavigationItem`:**

`initWithImage:style:target:action:` creates colored images and converts `plain` to `bordered`.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I'm confused though; both the [iOS HIG](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW8) and the [UIBarButtonItem API docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIBarButtonItem_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIBarButtonItem/initWithImage:style:target:action:) state that the image is used as a mask to derive the button's appearance using its alpha values only. Is the actual behaviour documented by Apple?

Comment: (To clarify: I'm not arguing with your answer, I can see with my own eyes, in my own code, that you're dead right and I've given you a +1 for your trouble. But the behaviour is totally different to what Apple's own docs state, so I'm naturally curious as to whether I've just missed something.)

Comment: I was also quite confused and spent 30 minutes figuring this out. It's why I posted my answer because I hoped someone would find use.  The behavior definitely is not obvious and against what the docs say.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, you are setting an UIButton as the subview of an UIBarButtonItem.
UIBarButtonItem is already a button, so you shouldn't add another button as the subview.

Try this:

```
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icon.png"];
rootViewController.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:image] autorelease];
```

Comment: `UIBarButtonItem` does not respond to `initWithImage:` but to `initWithImage:image style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(action)`
However, the image is still black instead of white.

Comment: I'm sorry, that's what I meant indeed.

Strange... What is the actual color of the image file?

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. I Noted that the @2X images were used instead...