# No Shadow/Emboss on UIBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiimage, uibarbuttonitem

I've got a problem with an custom UIBarButtonItem. When I create an custom UIBarButtonItem via

```
 [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"FilterIcon.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(filterTouched:)];
```

the resulting button does not have the "embossed" look, that the system items achieve by placing a semi-transparent black shadow behind their icons.

[image: Left: system item, right: custom item]

On the left you see the "Organize" system bar button item, rightthe result of the code from above.

Creating the shadow in the resource is futile, because iOS/Cocoa only used the mask of the image and discards any color information.

Interestingly, if I create the bar button item in the Interface-Builder it looks fine. However, in the context of my problem, I need to create the button item in code.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is Objective-C version of James Furey's script.

```
- (UIImage *)applyToolbarButtonStyling:(UIImage *)oldImage {
    float shadowOffset = 1;
    float shadowOpacity = .54;
    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, oldImage.size.width, oldImage.size.height);
    CGRect shadowRect = CGRectMake(0, shadowOffset, oldImage.size.width, oldImage.size.height);
    CGRect newRect = CGRectUnion(imageRect, shadowRect);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newRect.size, NO, oldImage.scale);
    CGContextRef ctx = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextScaleCTM(ctx, 1, -1);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(ctx, 0, -(newRect.size.height));
    CGContextSaveGState(ctx);
    CGContextClipToMask(ctx, shadowRect, oldImage.CGImage);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor colorWithWhite:0 alpha:shadowOpacity].CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, shadowRect);
    CGContextRestoreGState(ctx);
    CGContextClipToMask(ctx, imageRect, oldImage.CGImage);
    CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(ctx, [UIColor colorWithWhite:1 alpha:1].CGColor);
    CGContextFillRect(ctx, imageRect);
    UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

Answer (score 7):

I think the *reason* this occurs is covered by these answers to another question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3476424/1210490

https://stackoverflow.com/a/6528603/1210490

UIBarButtonItems behave differently depending on where you programmatically attach them. If you attach them to a toolbar, they'll become white "embossed" icons. If you attach them to a navigation bar, they won't.

I've spent the last few hours writing a function to apply toolbar UIBarButtonItem styling to UIImages. **It's written in C# for MonoTouch**, but I'm sure you'll be able to tweak it to Obj-C no problemo...

```
UIImage ApplyToolbarButtonStyling(UIImage oldImage)
{
    float shadowOffset = 1f;
    float shadowOpacity = .54f;
    RectangleF imageRect = new RectangleF(PointF.Empty, oldImage.Size);
    RectangleF shadowRect = new RectangleF(new PointF(0, shadowOffset), oldImage.Size);
    RectangleF newRect = RectangleF.Union(imageRect, shadowRect);
    UIGraphics.BeginImageContextWithOptions(newRect.Size, false, oldImage.CurrentScale);
    CGContext ctxt = UIGraphics.GetCurrentContext();
    ctxt.ScaleCTM(1f, -1f);
    ctxt.TranslateCTM(0, -newRect.Size.Height);
    ctxt.SaveState();
    ctxt.ClipToMask(shadowRect, oldImage.CGImage);
    ctxt.SetFillColor(UIColor.FromWhiteAlpha(0f, shadowOpacity).CGColor);
    ctxt.FillRect(shadowRect);
    ctxt.RestoreState();
    ctxt.ClipToMask(imageRect, oldImage.CGImage);
    ctxt.SetFillColor(UIColor.FromWhiteAlpha(1f, 1f).CGColor);
    ctxt.FillRect(imageRect);
    UIImage newImage = UIGraphics.GetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphics.EndImageContext();
    return newImage;
}
```

So, a UIBarButtonItem that used to look like this:

[image: Before]

Created instead with the function above, like this:

```
UIBarButtonItem barButtonItem = new UIBarButtonItem(ApplyToolbarButtonStyling(UIImage.FromFile("MusicIcon.png")), UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, delegate {});
```

Would now look like this:

[image: After]

Hope this helps someone in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the read. Actually, this looks to me like Apple is having an inconsistency issue there. I've checked some default apps, and the few icons in the Navigation Bars have the embossed look (e.g. the plus icon in Contacts or the write button in Messages).

Comment: My gosh, thanks a lot for this elaborate effort. Sadly, I don't have time to incorporate this into our current version of the product, but will try for the next release. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Take note of the shadow offset in James Furey's script.
I've made the following experience:

```
float shadowOffset = 1.0f // for a UIBarButtonItem in UINavigationItem
float shadowOffset = 0.0f // for a UIBarButtonItem in UIToolBar
```

This was observed with iOS 6.1 SDK.

(Now obsolete under iOS 7)