# bar button item image is turning to white icon even if its black

Tags: ios, ios5, ios6, uibarbuttonitem

I am using these icons as bar button item in a toolbar
 http://stopiransnukes.org/images/home_icon.png
 and
http://www.bladmuziekplus.nl/shop/files/images/icon_home.png
 But background image is converted to white automatically even if its black.

I tried setting image background via code but still its turning into white.

Manually : I have Dragged+Dropped the above image  to the project.I have selected the bar button item and on 4th option on the right bar (shield icon) select different tint and under bar button drop-down image is set to the above image.

Programmatically :

```
  [self.homeButton setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: [UIColor blackColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,nil] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

   [[self.homeButton] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home_icon.png"]];
```

How do I fix it ?
Thanks in Advance.

.

Comment: you need to post your code or screenshot for how you are adding a buttons in your toolbar

Comment: Why dont you try this. just drag and drop a uibutton and add a image to it in the storyboard itself and add that to uibarbuttonitem by just drag and drop itself and adding a action method to the uibutton makes what u need..try it in storyboard itself. no need of any code except an action method for a button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

viewDidLoad

```
[super viewDidLoad];

//uıbarButtonItem firstButtonItem,secondButtonItem
UIImage* firstButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"firstImageName"];;
CGRect frameimg = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
UIButton * someButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frameimg];
[someButton setBackgroundImage:firstButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[someButton addTarget:self action:@selector(goToUserProfile)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
self.firstButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:someButton];


UIImage* secondButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"secondImageName"];
frameimg = CGRectMake(0, 0, 30, 30);
someButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frameimg];
[someButton setBackgroundImage:secondButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[someButton addTarget:self action:@selector(likePhoto)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[someButton setTag:1];
self.secondButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:someButton];

[self.toolbar setItems:[self addItemsToToolbar]];
```

AddItemsToToolbar Method

```
- (NSMutableArray *)addItemsToToolbar{
NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
UIBarButtonItem *flexSpace = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
[items addObject:flexSpace];
[items addObject:self.firstButtonItem];
[items addObject:flexSpace];
[items addObject:self.secondButtonItem];
return items;
```

}

Answer (score 2):

This is a step by step process to add a image into `UIButton` and add that `UIButton` as a `custom view` inside the `UIBarButtonItem` in the `storyboard` itself.. I will add some images for you to understand this totally..

**step 1:** Drag and drop the `toolbar` in `storyboard` view
[image: Drag and drop the toolbar in your view]

**step 2:** Drag and drop the `UIButton` in your `view`

[image]

**step 3:** Drag and drop the image in your `UIButton`

[image]

**step 4:** Drag and drop the `UIButton` in the toolbar and now you can in the right side that it is added inside of the `UIBarButtonItem`. now you just have to connect an action method for your button.

[image]

Comment: I have tried the same but now place an image as background icon instead of icon Even if its black it turns into white.

Comment: Cannot customize by the above method

Comment: or if yes then how .I tried to add on with the code but it still does not work

Comment: I thought you asked as how to add it in the storyboard.. its ok.. Both works in a same way.

Comment: Is it possible to link the storyboard bar button item to the code and add customization to that button via code ? for eg: outlet name of the button.addBackgroundImage=something  .

Comment: Thanks for step by step graphical representation it would help others too.

Comment: ofcourse you can connect to the outlet whatever u want and also u can customize it..

Comment: But when I try to do so its not working in this case  only ,its working in textfield and other case but customizing bar button item is not possible via storyboard but code it is !!

Comment: who said you cannot customize bar button item in the storyboard?? I showed how to do that exactly in the above answer. Look at that clearly. What @Gungor Basa explained in code as well as the same thing, we are doing in the storyboard itself. First understand the whole thing, what his code doing.

Answer (score 1):

This is the normal behaviour, you can read about it in the Human Interface Guidelines.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/IconsImages/IconsImages.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH14-SW8

If you want to change that you need to write your own subclasses.

Comment: So what I am supposed to to do to keep the same image as saved in project.In this case black.Please tell me how to do this ? I am still confused.

Comment: This should help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3431961/uibarbuttonitem-icon-white-when-added-via-ib-black-when-added-programmatically

Comment: I have already created a bar button item on storyboard.How do I link this code to that.I tried the above code but its not working

Comment: To access the bar button item from your storyboard you need to add an IBOutlet property in your view controller and link it. It might be better to init and add the bar button completely in code, since you get an already initialized object if you use storyboard. Make sure to use initWithCustomView:

Comment: I have created Bar Button item and on storyboard, can I add this code to that item created? Basically How cab I link the button to the button features in this case the image background.

Answer (score 0):

```
UIImage* infoButtonImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"info_button.png"];;
CGRect frameimg = CGRectMake(0, 0, infoButtonImage.size.width, infoButtonImage.size.height);
UIButton * someButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frameimg];
[someButton setBackgroundImage:infoButtonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[someButton addTarget:self action:@selector(actionOfButton)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
UIBarButtonItem * infoButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:someButton];
```

This code is going to solve your problem

Comment: I have already created a bar button item on storyboard.How do I link this code to that.I tried the above code but its not working .

Comment: Do I need to add infoButton to toolbar view ? Coz  the variable infoButton id unused

Comment: @JacobWood Honestly I don't know how to do that from interface builder but I can help you with code. Firstly you need to have an array of UIBarButtonItem which you want to add. All elements have to be UIBarButonItem than you can call this method for fill the toolbar. "[self.toolbar setItems:items];"

Comment: @JacobWood **[self.toolbar setItems:items];** items is a NSArray of UIBarButtonItem